# Is deleting a hash faster than deleting keys individually? or does deleting a hash just iterate over the keys in the hash?

Tags: caching, redis, stackexchange.redis, spring-data-redis, node-redis

Currently trying to build a caching system that's efficient to update. I will need to delete my hashes here and there. Would it be faster to delete a whole hash at once or are there no performance differences in deleting a whole hash?

I'm wondering this as the redis documentation states the DEL command has a time complexity of O(M) for hashes which I'm unsure means it's referring to single key deletion within the hash (amount of keys in the hash i choose to delete) or the hash overall.

I'm expecting it to be O(1) for deletion of an entire hash but I could be wrong.

Comment: You should run the experiment and time it (what's the distribution of your keys, how many entries etc).  I would expect deleting the entire hash to be much faster for a sufficiently large number of keys.

Comment: If you pass each single field key every time, I guess it's slower than delete the whole key. Because the networking IO consumed the most time. If you use `hdel` and pass all fields, I suppose it's the same